# how to overwrite a html file in R

Tags: r, gsub, overwrite

I am trying to substitue the email address from a html file into ANTI SPAM Format and again Export it as nospam.html file.
I try to use gsub() function to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working. What's the Problem?
Thank you!!!

```
datei <- scan("https://isor.univie.ac.at/about-us/People.html", sep = "\n", what= "character")
#pattern.email <- "[a-z]+[.]+[a-z]+?[@]+[a-z]+"
reg.email <- "\\<[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}\\>" #works

stelle.email <-gregexpr(reg.email, datei, ignore.case = TRUE) #works

unlist(stelle.email)
res.email<- regmatches(datei, stelle.email)

datei2<-gsub(reg.email, "vornameDOTnameNO-SPAMunivieDOTacDOTat", x = datei)

write(datei2, file = "nospam.html")
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working", can you be more specific and indicate what exactly is not working.

Comment: I'm suspicious about your `reg.email`. can you debug to see what it actually matches? I am reminded of this: "When in doubt, keep adding slashes until it works." -- Joran Elias (on how to escape a backslash in R)

Comment: There are two problems with your assignment to `datei2`: either (1) you are replacing the static regex with a static string within `datei` (it never occurs); or (2) you really mean `gsub(res.email, ...)`, in which case you are ignoring [`?gsub`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) when it says that it only uses the first from `pattern=` with a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be informative to know that `regmatches` (for *extracting* matched substrings) also has the companion `regmatches<-` function (for *replacing* matched substrings). See [`?regmatches`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regmatches.html).

So there's no need for `gsub`, just:

```r
datei <- scan("https://isor.univie.ac.at/about-us/People.html", sep = "\n", what= "character")
# Read 481 items
reg.email <- "\\<[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}\\>" #works
stelle.email <- gregexpr(reg.email, datei, ignore.case = TRUE) #works

# for proof, first look at a substring with a "known" email:
substr(datei[268], 236, 281)

### the only new/different line of code, remove your gsub
regmatches(datei, stelle.email) <- "vornameDOTnameNO-SPAMunivieDOTacDOTat"

# now look at the same portion of that one substring, now updated
substr(datei[268], 236, 281)

write(...)
```